# AntPathRequestMatcher is deprecated. What is the replacment method?

Tags: java, spring-security

I'm trying to create a logout option for login page.

```java
  AntPathRequestMatcher pathRequestMatcher = new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout");
  http.logout().logoutRequestMatcher(pathRequestMatcher);
```

Since `org.springframework.security.web.util.AntPathRequestMatcher.AntPathRequestMatcher` is `deprecated` in Spring Security 4.1.6, which class I supposed to use?

Comment: @seelenvirtuose I saw it when I imported `org.springframework.security.web.util.AntPathRequestMatcher`

Comment: :D sorry @codeer it is `4.1.6.RELEASE`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The AntPathRequestMatcher has moved packages between Spring 3.x and Spring 4.x

As quoted from [Migrating from Spring Security 3.x to 4.x](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/migrate/current/3-to-4/html5/migrate-3-to-4-jc.html#m3to4-deprecations-web-rm):

> The RequestMatcher and its implementations have moved from the package
> `org.springframework.security.web.util` to
> `org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher`.
>
> Specifically
>
> `org.springframework.security.web.util.AntPathRequestMatcher` →
> `org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher`